# Which TOS characters do we see in TNG-era canon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

I recall seeing Spock and McCoy on *TNG*, but which other *TOS* regular bridge crew do we see in TNG-era canon i.e. *TNG*, *DS9*, *VOY* and the *TNG* movies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New Material

- Kirk - *Star Trek Generations*
- Spock - *TNG* 'Unification Pt 1 & Pt 2'
- Scotty - *TNG* 'Relics' and *Star Trek Generations*
- Sulu - *VOY* 'Flashback'
- McCoy - *TNG* 'Encounter at Faropoint Pt 2'
- Rand - *VOY* 'Flashback'
- Chekhov - *Star Trek Generations*

## Re-used footage

- Uhura - *DS9* 'Trials and Tribble-ations'

The notable absence is Christine Chapel

and, bonus character (courtesty @iMerchant)

- Sarek - *TNG* 'Sarek', 'Unification Pt 1'

Comment: Spock and some of the others weren't in Generations.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon you are correct about Spock- my apologies!

Comment: Interesting to note that original TOS Spock not only spanned across to the TNG era, but also into Abramsverse. I think he's the only one to span all three.

Comment: I don't know if "Trials and Tribble-ations" and "Flashback" should count. In the first, the DS9 crew time travelled back to the TOS time frame. In the second, Tuvok was experiencing a memory from his past in the TOS time frame. As I read the question, though it says "TNG-era *canon*", it *feels* more like it is asking which TOS characters have been seen in the other time frames themselves.

Comment: Along those lines, we would be left with only Kirk in "Generations", Spock in "Unification", Scotty in "Relics" and McCoy in "Encounter at Farpoint".

Comment: @RemyLebeau the intent was more to see which characters we see later on. The difference in Tribbles and Flashback is that new footage was used

Comment: Another important character that deserves a special shout out IMO, although not part of the bridge crew, is Sarek.

Comment: Uhura is in Trials and Tirbble-ations. She's in the bar when the Tribbles are first seen.

Comment: @Alarion so she is; this is what happens when you refer to episodes you haven't seen for ages!  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Of those listed, only Kirk, Scotty, and Chekov were in the movie, yet your sentence states otherwise, Dr. Soong.

Comment: Does Star Trek VI count as "TNG canon"? If so, Sulu and Rand are back in.